# Red5 setup guide?

Tags: red5

I've been looking for a online service that will let me stream a movie with my friends and family. However, services like Rabb.it do not include iTunes. Now, I could log-into itunes on rabb.it, however I cannot access the movie through the browser. Being that said, I've been looking for a place I can stream the movie and not be banned i.e. twitch, youtube, and so forth and such however there is no options like that.

So I came across Red5 however, there is no tutorials to set it up so I'm at a loss.

Is anyone able to guide me, to setting it up?

Comment: There are a large number of tutorials for Red5; its been around for 11 years, but most are out of date and things do get stale. The best option for you if you want to run your own server is Red5 Pro (which is not free) or using the Amazon transcoder service.